# loop data from state with react.js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm doing my first reactjs app and i have run into some troubles. 
This is my feature (child) component that i call from my base file.

```
 var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  var React = require('react');
 var ConfigurationService = require('../configurationService');

 class Feature extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        features: null
    };
    this.getConfiguration();

}   
getConfiguration() {
    var self = this;
    var config = ConfigurationService.getConfiguration('test', 'test').then(function (config) {
        self.setState({ features: config.data.Features })
    });       
}
render() {
    if (this.state.features) {
        return (<div> {
            this.state.features.map(function (feature) {
                <span>feature.Description</span>
            })
        }
        </div>)
    }
    else {
        return <div>no data</div>
    }
}
}

module.exports = Feature;
```

It calls my api and collects data that looks like this:

[image]

For like a 10th of a second it shows the "no data" but then i guess that it succeeds to grab the data and that this.state.features no longer is null.
But even though features isn't null it doesn't show anything in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything inside map body, 2nd you need to use `{}` to print `feature.Description` because its a dynamic data, and 3rd is you need to assign unique key to each element inside loop otherwise it will throw warning.

Use this:

```
if (this.state.features) {
    return (
        <div> 
            {
               this.state.features.map(function (feature, i) {
                  return  <span key={feature.Id}>{feature.Description}</span>
               })
            }
       </div>
    )
....
```

Or you can use `arrow function` also, like this:

```
if (this.state.features) {
    return (
        <div> 
            {
              this.state.features.map((feature) =>  <span key={feature.Id}> {feature.Description} </span>)
            }
       </div>
    )
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) It is sort of weird that you have to return a value inside of the html i think. But i guess that is just something that you have to get use to :P

Comment: it's not html, map expect a function that will get called for each element, it will be similar to giving a function name and defining that name outside of render method, and you need to return some value from that function :)

Comment: One thing though, array `index` as `key` is an `anti-pattern` as the array can change but the `index` will point to a different element then and cause problems with React's diffing algorithm. Since the `feature` object has an `Id` that should be used. Also don't worry about the syntax. It's not `HTML` but `JSX` which is Javascript.

Comment: @mrinalmech thanks, i was not sure about the uniqueness of id's, that's why i used index :)

Comment: @Mayank - No worries. `Ids` from backend APIs are almost always unique as they are usually generated by the database.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `map` works. You need to have a `return` statement inside the `map` which is basically for each element of the array return so and so.

```
return (
        <div> {
            this.state.features.map(function (feature) {
               return  (<span key={feature.Id}>{feature.Description}</span>)
            })
        }
        </div>
 )
```

Here for example for each `feature` it is returning a `span` with the contents as `feature.Description`.

Also like `Mayank Shukla` pointed out a `key` is important. `keys` are basically used by react to compare the new `DOM` when state changes to the old `DOM` and make only those changes which are required (instead of re-rendering the entire component). The `keys` have to be unique so use the `feature.Id` as a key as that is unique. Don't use array indices as `keys` as the array might change and then the `indices` will point to wrong elements in the new array.